# gvim does not recognize certain directories or files (Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: windows-7, powershell, 64-bit, vim

I'm having a weird issue with gvim on Windows 7 64-bit.  I am using gvim 7.2, and the "c:\windows\gvim.bat" is the executable that is first on my path if I just type "gvim" on the powershell command line.  Note that I've tried both the gvim.bat file and calling gvim.exe directly.

For some reason, there is a certain directory on my file system which vim does not seem to see or recognize.  I can navigate to this directory in cmd, powershell, windows explorer, etc., and I can see the files in the directory.  I can also edit the files in notepad or another text editor, but if I try to open any of the files in gvim, it does not open the file, but rather reports "[New DIRECTORY]".  If I try to open the folder itself in gvim, it does not open it in the vim directory browser as I would expect, but instead it reports "[New FILE]".

If I open gvim, and do File->Open... and navigate to where the folder should be, it is not visible in the open file dialog.

What would cause a directory (or files) to not be visible or recognized by gvim?

Note that the directory I'm having problems with is the PowerShellCommunityExtensions module.  I currently have this installed here:  "c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Pscx\".  The Pscx folder is the one that gvim will not recognize.  I have other modules in this Modules folder which gvim can open successfully.

Comment: Someone had a comment here saying that it might have something to do with the windows\system32 folder...  It looks like that might be the problem, if I copy the Pscx module to my local c:\users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\" folder, I can edit the files.

Comment: I started that comment and then something came up and it was submitted prematurely. Depending on the architecture of the program you are using, the 64-bit OS "redirects" some requests to the SysWOW64 directory, which is the 64-bit equivalent of System32.

Comment: Oh interesting...  that is very strange.  Sure enough, if I put the  Pscx folder in c:\windows\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx, I can see it and open in in gvim.  Jay - if you want some points, you can put in an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I also noticed if I went into c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\ and did a git clone of some remote ps module, the downloaded files end up in the syswow64 equivalent folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently GVIM.exe is a 32-bit app that appears to Windows 7 as a legacy app which causes Windows  Vista/7 to virtualize access to the file system and registry.  Access to C:\Windows\System32 is redirected to C:\Windows\SysWOW4.  Writes to C:\Program Files are redirected to C:\ProgramData or C:\Users\\AppData\Local\VirtualStore.  And access to the registry node HKLM:\Software is redirected to HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node.  The following [MS Support URL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387) explains it a bit further.

Comment: "Apparently", *your* Gvim.exe is 32-bit.  I've been using a 64bit "gvim.exe" since 2016.  The problem is that gvim is compiled for MANY different platforms so there are many options one can choose, so you have to look around to be sure you find the right version for you.  It isn't just 32/64 bits, but also whether or not various interpretive languages are built as run-time loadables, Visual Studio support, etc.  Links come and go, so better to search for what you want.   You definately don't want to be running a 32-bit vim on a 64-bit OS.